# Como limitar una clase para un elemento del DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, librería

En mi proyecto tengo una librería para darle estilo Material a todas las paginas.

Tengo un input al que no quiero que le dé estilo esa librería, quiero que ese input esté libre de estilo, pues es generado por otra librería de JS y muestra algunos errores de apariencia.

Quisiera saber si es posible algo como esto:

```
<input id="inputGeneradoPorJS" type="text" class="notClass:input_Style_Material">
```

Las dos librerias, tanto la de JS como la de CSS están obfuscadas y .min, por lo que me es imposible meterle mi propio codigo para lograr lo que busco.

Comment: Porque no usas el id para aplicar los estilos de un lado y no le aplicas la clase de la libreria?

Comment: lo digo porque si la clase es la que le aplica esos estilos al input entonces simplemente no usarla en ese input... pero si se los aplica directamente al input, la cosa ya es un poco distinta...

Answer (score 0):

No exite  una alternativa tal como lo indicas:`notClass:input_Style_Material`, pero exiten algunas reglas de `CSS` y el DOM con el cual quizá puedas solucionar tu problema.

Por ejemplo un librería como `Material` que es la que indicas, puede tener un solo estilo para todos los `input`, algo asi como esto:

```css
input{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="number">
```

También pueden incluir algunas `class` para diferenciar entre una y otra. EJ:

```css
input{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.red{
    background:red;
}
.green{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="red">
<input type="number" class="green">
```

Y puedes agregar tantas clases deses a tu etiqueta y el DOM siempre da prioridad al que esta mas a la izquierda.EJ:

```css
input{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.red{
    background:red;
}
.green{
    background:green;
}
/*esta puede ser una clase que agrega el JS*/
.blue{
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="red blue">
<input type="number" class="green blue">
```

Como veras las clases red y green han sido hechas a un lado por el DOM y tomo los valores de la `class` mas a la izquierda que seria blue, en tu caso podrian ser las clases del `js` que usas, haciendo que tus estilos no se vean como deseas.Hasta aqui tu problema.

Más allá de las `class` tenemos la propiedad `style` en html para poder aplicar nuestro estilo a la "fuerza", ya que el DOM da mayor prioridad a esta propiedad ante los `css`.

```css
input{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.red{
    background:red;
}
.green{
    background:green;
}
/*como no puede deshacerme de esta clase aplico style en la etiqueta html para poder solucionar mi problema*/
.blue{
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="red blue" style="background:#7E1D8D">
<input type="number" class="green blue" style="background:#7E1D8D">
```

Quizá tu problema no solo sea con el `background`, pero como no diste mas información trate de hacer un ejemplo completo de como podrías solucionar tu problema.

Comment: @LuisEduardoMoreno, espero se entienda.